# Return multiple values with df.apply()

Tags: python, pandas

In the program below, I want to return message as a separate variable when `df.apply(custom_function)` is called.
Is it possible to do so

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Column1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'Column2': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def custom_function(row):
    message = "Done"
    return row['Column1'] + row['Column2']


df['Result'] = df.apply(custom_function, axis=1)

print(df)
```

`[df['Result'] = df.apply(custom_function, axis=1), message] = df.apply(custom_function, axis=1)` doesn't work and `df['Result'] = df.apply(custom_function, axis=1)` with `return row['Column1'] + row['Column2'], message` adds message to each row.

Comment: Do you mind adding the expected output?

Comment: "adds message to each row.": yes, that is what you'd expect.

Comment: I'm going to say no, you can't do that. It doesn't make sense in the context of `df.apply`. You could assign the result to a series (like the Result column you use now), and then explode that series to obtain the individual parts. But that requires extra steps, and it will just look confusing: when I see `df.apply(some_function)`, I expect that `some_function` returns a single value. So perhaps try to think of another approach and avoid this trickery.

Comment: @rpanai, it's another df (or could be a dict as well).

Comment: This looks like an X-Y problem. Why do you want to use this? What do you, ultimately, want to achieve with it? Do you want to return some flag ("success" or "fail") with the calculated result?

Comment: Your function is not returning `message` is just setting it to `"Done"`. What you want to do with the variable `message` is not clear.

Comment: @alec_djinn Check the (slightly confusing) code below the code block, which has `return row['Column1'] + row['Column2'], message`. The OP shows the current working code, and asks how to amend it for the requested purpose.

Comment: Please have a look at [ask] and how to write a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like that:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Column1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'Column2': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def custom_function(row):
    message = "Done"
    return row['Column1'] + row['Column2'], message

df[['Result', 'Status']] = df.apply(custom_function, axis=1, result_type='expand')
df


   Column1  Column2  Result Status
0        1       10      11   Done
1        2       20      22   Done
2        3       30      33   Done
3        4       40      44   Done
4        5       50      55   Done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Column1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'Column2': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def custom_function(row):
    message = "Done"
    result = row['Column1'] + row['Column2']
    return result, message

# Apply the custom_function
df[['Result', 'Message']] = df.apply(custom_function, axis=1, result_type='expand')

print(df)
```

Output:

```
Column1  Column2  Result Message
0        1       10      11    Done
1        2       20      22    Done
2        3       30      33    Done
3        4       40      44    Done
4        5       50      55    Done
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with *not* using `.apply` then I suggest to use comprehension following way

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2,3,4,5],'y':[6,7,8,9,0]})


def my_function(row):
    row_dict = row._asdict()
    row_dict['total'] = row_dict['x'] + row_dict['y']
    row_dict['product'] = row_dict['x'] * row_dict['y']
    return row_dict


df2 = pd.DataFrame(my_function(i) for i in df.itertuples(index=False))
print(df2)
```

gives output

```
   x  y  total  product
0  1  6      7        6
1  2  7      9       14
2  3  8     11       24
3  4  9     13       36
4  5  0      5        0
```

Explanation: I use [pandas.DataFrame.itertuples](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html) to iterate over rows as [namedtuples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) which I feed into my_function, in which I convert it to `dict` (namedtuples are immutable, so it is impossible to change them) add computed values and return altered dict, then create new DataFrame from altered dicts.